# Echo IMG in PHP

Tags: php

This has been killing me for two hours now and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Its just a simple "echo" when the variable equals a certain number and I have narrowed it to the img part cuz this works:

```
if ($sex==1) {
    $_SESSION['display pic']="images/male.jpg";
}
```

but this crashes:

```
if ($sex==1) {
    $_SESSION['display pic'] = "images/male.jpg"; 
    echo '<img src="../images/male.gif" height="100">';
}
```

likewise with this:

```
echo "<a href=\"".$big[$c]."\" target=_blank title=\"See full image\"   onclick=\"window.open('".$big[$c]."','popup','width=".$w[$c].",height=".$h[$c].",toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=no,resizable=no,minimize=no,maximize=no,fullscreen=no,dependent=no'); return false;\"><img src=\"".$path[$c]."T/".$name[$c]."\"></a>";
```

This is in a function and outputted in a DIV BTW. It displays the image but stops the rest of the script. I've been hung up on this for so long, please help.

Comment: What do you mean "crashes"? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: it just stops doing everything else. When I use the first code all links on the page work. When I use the second and third, all links stop. There is no error message given

Comment: Do you have errors enabled? Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your code.

Comment: are you initializing the session before using the session variable using session_start() ?

Comment: @Styphon yes and it gives no error

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar the SESSION part works. Its when I add the echo part that it stops working

Comment: I have dozens of links in DIVs using onClick. With the first code they all work but if I use the second code or third code I get the display I want but none of the links function

Comment: @StevenVanerp view the source code of your page, and see what is in there, is what you intended to have.

Comment: @Arian yes all looks well. The links are present but not operational

Comment: @Arian actually there was a glitch in the source code. Went thru it character by character and found using ' instead of " made it work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you got firebug? Or inspecting source with chrome will show javascript errors

Comment: @StevenVanerp No Problem, glad I could help... they say programming is 10% coding and 90% debugging, lol

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
       $OnClick =  "onclick=\"window.open('".$big[$c]."','popup','width=$w[$c],height=$h[$c],toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,minimize=no,maximize=no,fullscreen=no,dependent=no');return false;\" "; 

        echo "<a href='".$big[$c]."' target='_blank' title='See full image'   $OnClick > 
                <img src='".$path[$c].'T/'.$name[$c]."'>                        
         </a>";
```

Comment: Same result. Img appears and is clickable as desired but no links work and no error msg

Comment: I have tested in my instance, it is working fine, clicking image open a popup window. Did you used my latest code?